# Merging sublists with same initial element by substituting null values

Tags: python, list, matrix, merge

I want to merge sublists with the same initial first element, but instead of adding the other values one after the other, I want to substitute values where they are None.
I have a matrix with sublists, each sublist contains 7 values: number of the element, score A, score B, score C, score D, score E, score F. So far for each sublist there is only one value (even if this is the same for different sublists), but I want to merge sublists that contain different scores for the same element.

I have

```
sub_lists = [(1,None,None,12,None,None,None),
             (2,67,None,None,None,None,None), 
             (2,None,None,83,None,None,None),
             ...]
```

So for each sublist there is only 1 score indicated while the others are null. The result I am looking for is

```
sub_lists = [(1,None,None,12,None,None,None),
             (2,67,None,83,None,None,None),
             ...]
```

What I have tried is

```
res = []
for sub in sub_lists:
    if res and res[-1][0] == sub[0]:
        res[-1].extend(sub[1:])
    else:
        res.append([ele for ele in sub])
res = list(map(tuple, res))
```

But this only adds the values one after the other, resulting in

```
sub_lists = [(1,None,None,12,None,None,None),
             (2,67,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,83,None,None,None),
             ...]
```

Does someone know how to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[adam-smooch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10761353/adam-smooch)

he was right I think

```
sub_lists=[
  (1,None,None,12,None,None,None),
  (2,67,None,None,None,None,None),
  (2,None,None,83,None,None,None)
]
def my_combine(l1, l2):
  l1 = list(l1)
  l2 = list(l2)
  for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] is None:
      l1[i] = l2[i]

  return l1

results = dict()
for sl in sub_lists:
  if sl[0] not in results:
    results[sl[0]] = sl[1:]
  else:
    results[sl[0]] = my_combine(results[sl[0]], sl[1:])
print(results)

# desired outcome.
# sub_lists=[
#   (1,None,None,12,None,None,None),
#   (2,67,None,83,None,None,None)
# ]
```

I think @Adam Smooch was right I am modified it a bit

Comment: Thank you, this works. Do you think there is any way instead of a dictionary I can have sublists or tuples? This is because I need to write the elements into a csv file and it works better with matrices

Comment: add the following line to the end of the code and you will get it in the form of nested lists ```output = list(results.keys()) + list(results.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

since sub-lists' first numbers will be unique at the end, you could use a dictionary.

so do something like:

```
def my_combine(l1, l2):
  l1 = list(l1)
  for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] is None:
      l1[i] = l2[i]

  return tuple(l1)

results = dict()
for sl in sub_lists:
  if sl[0] not in results:
    results[sl[0]] = sl[1:]
  else:
    results[sl[0]] = my_combine(results[sl[0]], sl[1:])
```

Comment: I tried it and got this error ```[i] = l2[i]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub_lists=[(1,None,None,12,None,None,None),(2,67,None,None,None,None,None),(2,None,None,83,None,None,None)]
res = [] #resultant matrix
for sub in sub_lists:
    if res and res[-1][0] == sub[0]:
        valid = [] # let "valid" valid sublist that can be e added in resultant matrix.
        valid.append(res[-1][0]) # we will add the the first element of last sublist of resultant matrix, and rest of the elements of sub list of "sub_lists"
        valid.extend(sub[1:])
        res[-1] = valid
        print(sub)
    else:
        res.append([ele for ele in sub])
res = list(map(tuple, res))

print(res)

# desired outcome.
# sub_lists=[(1,None,None,12,None,None,None),(2,67,None,83,None,None,None)]
```

hope you got the desirable code,
and my comments make sense.☺️

feel free to ask anything further...!

Comment: I tried this and I still get a problem, in `res` I now only get the last sublist with one score rather than adding them, so I get `sub_lists=[(1,None,None,12,None,None,None),(2,None,None,83,None,None,None)]`

Comment: I'll be back on it...!